# drop down menu: how to make deactivate the 1st (selected) option?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Here is the dropdown I'm using:

```
<form name="my_form_name">
<select name="my_ddmenu_name">
<option value="#" selected>dd menu title (should not act as a link)</option>
<option value="link to page 1">1st Link name</option>
<option value="link to page 2">2nd Link name</option>
<option value="link to page 3">3rd Link name</option>
<option value="link to page 4">4th Link name</option>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu1.value,'newtab')">
</select>
</form>
```

It's necessary for me to 
 - have a "Go" link, as above. Users should select their link of choice and then press "Go!" to visit the selected link.
 - open links in a new tab, as above.

So, how should I change the code above to deactivate the 1st (selected) option's link (currently leading to "#").

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
onClick="if(ddmenu1.value !== '#')window.open(ddmenu1.value,'newtab')"
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyv9j/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<option value="#" selected disabled>dd menu title (should not act as a link)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Go button must trigger a custom javascript that checks the value of your dropdown and then does the fancy link work.
JQuery would be my preference.

Comment: it was just a quick fix I needed so the solution by karim79 suits my needs just fine - Thank you too :)