# Deactivate the 'Submit' button for the selected value in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I searched the forum and came across [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004453/drop-down-menu-how-to-make-deactivate-the-1st-selected-option) thread but it didn't work for me. If there's something I missed please point me to it.

I have a dropdown in one of my websites and I'd like to deactivate the 'Submit' button when it shows the default selected value because people just click on 'Submit' and end up in 404 page.

I am a sucker for Javascript, so if someone could help would be really great.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="optin_box">
    <h3 style="color:#fff !important;">Box Title</h3>
       <p class="optin_text">Select your city:</p>
           <form name="redirect">
           <select name="selection">
          <option>My city</option>
          <optgroup label="Area 1">
          <option value="http://domain.com">City 1</option>
          <option value="http://domain2.com">City 2</option>
          <option value="http://domain3.com">City 3</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Area 2">
          <option value="domain4.com">City 4</option>
          <option value="domain5.com">City 5</option>
          </optgroup>                  
        </select>
        <br/>       
        <input class="button_link hover_fade red button_widget" style="font-size:14px;" type=button value="SUBMIT" onClick="WinOpen();">
        </form>
</div>
```

And here's some javascript I have:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function WinOpen() {
  var url=document.redirect.selection.value
  document.location.href=url
}
</script>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is that when someone sees 'My city' in the dropdown the 'SUBMIT' button should be deactivated.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Kat

Comment: Do you want pure JS?  You've included the jquery tag, but not used it anywhere.

Comment: Do be honest I am not sure what I need because I am not familiar with jquery. I was under the impression I was using it on 'onClick' in submit button.
Sorry is these are pretty basic.

Comment: No problem.  The `onclick` event handler is purely an inline handler to fire a javascript function.  You could have also attached it via javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of script that will do what you want, using the existing jQuery library that's already included in your page.  Just include this script and it will disable the button initially and then handle the select change afterwards.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("select[name=selection]").on("change", function() {
            $(this).closest("form")
                .find("input.button_link")
                .prop("disabled", $(this).val() == "#");
        })
            .trigger("change");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Note:**
This assumes that you added the value `#` to the initial option in the select, as you mentioned you had done previously.

Comment: No problem - glad to help.  Incidentally, nice looking site :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery (lib must be included)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

For conveniance, set an id on your dropdown

```
<select id="myselect" name="selection">
```

Also on your submit button

```
<input id="mybutton" .... />
```

Then use jquery to detect a change on your select

```
$('#mysselect').change(function() {
    if($('#mysselect').val() === 'My City') {
        $('#mybutton').prop( "disabled", true);    
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 - you covered more or less exactly what i was going to propose, even down to the detail of adding the id to the selectlist!! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Thomas. Unfortunately, I cannot make this work. I guess that's due to my lack of jquery knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First, specify IDs for your `<select>` and Submit button: it will easier to access them from JS. 
Second, add onChange event listener to know when user changed the drop box.

```
<select name="selection" id="mySelect" onchange="checkSelect();">
...
<input class="button_link hover_fade red button_widget" style="font-size:14px;" type=button value="SUBMIT" onClick="WinOpen();" id="mySubmit">
```

Then check values when User changes them:

```
function checkSelect()
{
 // Let domain5.com be wrong
   if (document.getElementById('mySelect').value == 'domain5.com'))
           document.getElementById('mySubmit').disabled = true;
   else
           document.getElementById('mySubmit').disabled = false;

}
```

It will be pure JS. You can use jQuery as others said.

There is an alternative way, to use `this` as a parameter sent to function. 
Then you will not need to parse DOM. 
Thanks to Archer for suggestion.

HTML will be like this:

```
<select name="selection" onchange="checkSelect(this);">
```

JS will change to this:

```
function checkSelect(element)
{
 // Let domain5.com be wrong
   if (element.value == 'domain5.com')
           document.getElementById('mySubmit').disabled = true;
   else
           document.getElementById('mySubmit').disabled = false;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for 'onchange', I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @namikini. I have tried what you're suggesting but it didn't work. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. You can check here http://tgg.test.topstagingsite.com/deals/

Comment: @kat_indo Authorization required (401 error). I can't view this page.

Comment: Sorry about that. You should be able to access it now.

Comment: @kat_indo It will not work because there is no option in your dropdown list with 'domain5.com' value. Replace `domain5.com` with wrong domain. To check multiple domains you must use an array of them and indexOf instead of simple comparsion.

Comment: Gotcha! I have added 'value="#" in '<option value="#">Γυμνάζομαι στο</option>' which is the default view and tested again.
It allows me to click the button but it changes the url to 'http://tgg.test.topstagingsite.com/deals/#'.
Is that the expected behavior?