# Drop-down Redirect - Submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

i am using wordpress and i would like to create a  drop down menu with select options and i found this thread which i think is exactly what i need [Deactivate the 'Submit' button for the selected value in dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688482/deactivate-the-submit-button-for-the-selected-value-in-dropdown-menu)  to be honest i don't know how to set up these elements html,js,css in order to achieve the result.I am a begginer and i would appreciate any kind of instructions.
Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

For instructions in HTML, CSS and JS go to the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) website.  I learned almost all that I know from there.  If you need specific help THEN come asking here.

Comment: Thank you pianoman for your suggestion, i am still reading and working from W3Schools.

Comment: Welcome, @Libor!  That site is great.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you are going to implement this in your WordPress themes `index.php` file. So, copy and paste the HTML code in to the `html` tag wherever you want to display the drop down box. Also copy and paste the javascript in to the `script` tag inside the `head` tag of the page. You can also paste the javascript code to a new file created inside the `js` folder inside the `themes` folder and call it from the `head` tag in `index.php` file. If you have any CSS you can either place it directly in the `style` tag inside `head` tag of `index.php` file or create a file in the `css` folder,copy the css code to it and call the CSS file from the `head` tag of `index.php` file.

Comment: Anoop Asok i tried to follow your instructions but i am a little bit confused and i just put the code to the text editor and works great!!I forgot to mention above.The drop menu option box i want to display it over a slider at home page.Every suggestion will be very much appreciated!